# Remove a single line from a very large file using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to remove a single line (the first match) towards the beginning of a 250GB file. The command i have is this:

```
sed -i '0,/matchstring/{/matchstring/d;}' file
```

This works great on a smaller file, but on the big file, it never exits. I understand there is `q` to tell sed to exit early, but I can't figure out how to add that into what I have here.

Comment: doesn't adding a q after the delete work? sed -i '/matchstring/{/matchstring/d;q}' file

Comment: Perhaps `sed -i '/matchstring/d' file`? Another solution may be to split the file in two using csplit, use sed to delete the errant line and then concatenate the files. Or in the same vein, make a copy up to the errant line, delete from the start to the errant line and the join the copy with the original.

Comment: I wonder if [tag:ed] might be better: `printf '%s\n' "/regex/" d wq | ed file`

Comment: @brunoff adding that seemed to delete the contents of the file :(

Comment: did you try without the "0," just as i have shown? i have tested here and it worked with small files.

Comment: How long have you let it run? You might test it with a file of *one ten-thousandth* the length of your real file, to get a time benchmark.

Comment: the usual way has to rewrite ~250G data anyway. does it work for you if it's replaced by a "blank" line?

Comment: @pynexj ok thats what i was afraid of. I don't really understand how the files work "under the hood". something that replaces it with blanks works great, the line doesn't need to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP mentioned in the comment that

> ... something that replaces it with blanks works great, the line doesn't need to be removed.

And the following solution assumes the line is near to the begining of the file <sup>(otherwise we need a bit more tricks to get the exact offset of the line and the intermediate "header" file can be avoided)</sup>.

```
[STEP 101] $ cat file
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
foo matchstring bar
hello 4
hello 5
hello 6
[STEP 102] $ sed '/matchstring/{s/./ /g;q;}' file > header
[STEP 103] $ cat header
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3

[STEP 104] $ dd conv=notrunc if=header of=file
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
44 bytes copied, 0.000892102 s, 49.3 kB/s
[STEP 105] $ cat file
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3

hello 4
hello 5
hello 6
[STEP 106] $
```

And if it works by converting the matched line into a *comment* line, just change `s/./ /g` to, for example, `s/./#/` in the `sed` command.

Comment: This works great and runtime is unaffected by length of file. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If @pynexj's idea works, how about a `perl` approach which replaces the target line with blanks of the same length without changing the total file size.

```
perl -ne '
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV;                       # filename specified at the last line
open(FH, "+< $file") or die "$file";    # open the file with "rw" mode
while (<FH>) {
    if (/matchstring/) {                # if the target string is found
        my $pos = tell(FH);             # get the current position (start of the next line)
        $pos -= length;                 # rewind to the start of the target line
        seek(FH, $pos, 0);              # update the file pointer
        my $spaces = " " x (length($_) - 1) . "\n";
                                        # generate string of whitespaces of the same length
        print FH $spaces;               # overwrite the current line with the whitespaces
        close(FH);                      # close the file
        exit;                           # exit the script
    }
}
' "file"
```

**[Update]**
I have benchmarked the performance of the `perl` script by generating
a 100GB file containing the target string in the halfway of the file.
It completed in 15 minutes on my 10 year old laptop equipped with 2.5" HDD
(not SSD). Modern machines will run much more faster.

Comment: OP says the line is in the beginning of the file so it should be very fast.

Comment: It looks like this will work too, i went with the @pynexj's answer because it fit better with the script i was writing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how to add that into what I have here.

Just replace `d` with `q`...

```
sed '0,/matchstring/{/matchstring/q}'
```

Because `q` is exiting, and you are matching from the first line, you could just:

```
sed '/matchstring/q'
```

Och, maybe you do not want the line with `matchstring` in the output. Then you could print the line, but if it's `matchstring` then quit:

```
sed -n '/matchstring/q;p'
```

Comment: But these removes all the lines from `matchstring` (included or excluded depending on which of the commands) to the end of the file. The OP seems to say he wants to delete _a single line_.